# Search results list doesn't take backticks and code blocks into consideration for MathJax/LaTeX

Tags: bug, search, mathjax

I noticed when I [searched for `math` on Amateur Radio Meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=math) that the search results list doesn't seem to be taking into account whether valid MathJax/LaTeX code is included in code blocks or not, but appears to simply display whatever occurs in the first few sentences of the post and then apply MathJax on top of that (presumably if MathJax is enabled on the site, which it is on Amateur Radio).

It is my opinion that **if MathJax/LaTeX code occurs in a code block** (whether four-spaces-indented or in backticks), **it should not be rendered in the search results but rather simply be displayed verbatim** (though not necessarily in a fixed-width font; that is a different question). However, it *should* be rendered if the code appears outside of a [code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as in that case the author of the post obviously intends for it to be rendered.