# Inconsistent rendering of mathjax in truncated post body blurbs

Tags: bug, search, mobile-web, mathjax

In search results, at least on the mobile site:

[image]

From https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7951+dimensionless.

Mathjax rendering is done after the blurb is generated, and so happens inconsistently and depends in whether or not the full mathjax is in the blurb.

I do not know what the correct behavior should be, or even if anything should be changed. It is very minor, but it *is* inconsistent.

Related:

- Presumably (same fundamental issue of naive mathjax rendering in search results): [Search results list doesn't take backticks and code blocks into consideration for MathJax/LaTeX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230549/230261)
- This one describes MathJax rendering taking place but failure to recognize the correct start tag: [Search results and MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281522/search-results-and-mathjax)
- Same issue, but in titles: [Truncating long formulae in titles breaks formatting in search result lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217389/truncating-long-formulae-in-titles-breaks-formatting-in-search-result-lists)